# How to delete Google App Engine OAuth 2.0 client ID?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I want to implement social media log-in feature to my site where I have to allow users to use their existing Google or Facebook credentials to log-in to my site.

I read some articles and found learned that for Google log-in, I need to use `Google+` API. So I added some Javascript and HTML code in my HTML page and tried to log in but I am getting following error.

```
401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

Application: mytestapplication

You can email the developer of this application at: shekhar@gmail.com

no registered origin
```

I tried to create new OAuth ID but already there are too many IDs and I am not able to delete any one of them. I have tried all the `client-id` present for this application but none of the `client-id` is working.

Can anyone please tell how do I implement `sign-in with google` feature? How to delete and create new `client-id`?

Answer (score 1):

The last line is important:

```
no registered origin
```

On the API Credentials page, click `Edit Settings` under the `Client ID for web application` section. Put your URL there (`http://example.com`).